# How to loop through a list of a generic type

Tags: c#

I need to loop through a list where the type is not known at compile-time. How to do that? The following code fails at runtime, conversion not allowed:

```
    Type objType = dataObject.GetType();
    List<string> strList = new List<string>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in objType.GetProperties())
    {
        var val = prop.GetValue(dataObject);

        if (prop.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("List"))   // Is there a better way?
        {
            foreach (object lval in (List<object>) val)  // Runtime failure (conversion not allowed)
            {
                strList.Add(lval.ToString());
            }
        }
        ...
```

Comment: What conversion fails? Can you post the complete exception here please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't know the type, then : generics may not be the best option:

```
IList list = val as IList; // note: non-generic; you could also
                           // use IEnumerable, but that has some
                           // edge-cases; IList is more predictable
if(list != null)
{
    foreach(object obj in list)
    {
        strList.Add(obj.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add something to what has already been said:

Your logic is flawed because `List<int>` (for example) is not a subclass of `List<object>`. `List<T>` is not covariant in its type parameter.

If it was, it would be legal to do this:

```
List<object> listOfObjects = new List<int>();
listOfObjects.Add("a string");
```

Read this to learn more about covariance/contravariance in C#:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had the (bad) idea that a list of objects was somehow more generic than a list of integers. Perhaps it is more generic but still no base class.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var propInfo in foobar.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var val = propInfo.GetValue(foobar, null);

    if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(propInfo.PropertyType))
    {
        var collectionItems = (IEnumerable)val;
        if (collectionItems != null)
        {
            foreach (object lval in collectionItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lval);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's hope that there are no `string` properties... (also, the `.Cast<object>` here is probably not worthwhile - if you are going to use `object`, `IEnumerable` is fine)

Comment: True, that was just taken from some generic objectcomparison class that I am using in some project. But using IList or adding null check for collectionItems will work, cast is not required though. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will be easier

```
 foreach (PropertyInfo prop in objType.GetProperties())
        {
            var val = prop.GetValue(x,null);

            if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType) && prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType)   // Is there a better way?
            {
                dynamic dd = val;
                foreach (object lval in dd)  
                {
                    strList.Add(lval.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: @Gerard in this sample also use `dynamic` variable in `foreach` instead of casting to anything